# Как добавить меш коллайдер на Trail Renderer?

Tags: c#, unity3d, mesh

Вопрос по Unity 5.

Можете подсказать как добавить меш на Trail Renderer. И можно ли получить точку пересечение двух Trail Renderer.

**Обновление**

У меня есть круг который движется и оставляет след от Trail Renderer-а.
Как определить есть объект который коснулся "хвоста"? Я хотел добавить меш коллайдер и проверить с помощью  OnCollisionEnter метода.

Comment: Не следует два разных вопроса записывать в один.

Comment: Что значит добавить меш на Trail Renderer? вы добавляете `Trail Renderer` на объект. А уже у объекта может быть меш.... Например Когда добавляете сферу - у нее есть меш. Хотите чтоб она оставляла след, тогда добавляйте к ней пустой объект, как children, а потомка добавляйте рендерер.... Это более правильный вариант.....но как бы то ни было - меш на рендерер накинуть нельзя. это нонсенс

Comment: тут два вопроса относящиеся к одному

Comment: я не конкретно задал вопрос имею в виду меш коллайдер

Comment: @Arman Вы пытаетесь что сделать? Что-то типа [Трона](http://img.youtube.com/vi/-3ODe9mqoDE/0.jpg) ? ))

Comment: @Arman Скорее всего придется заводить массив, или даже ArrayList, в который каждый определенный промежуток времени складировать позицию `Vector 3` объекта и удалять из него постипенно при уменьшении трейла...... При этом проверять у другого объекта находится ли одна из точек этого Листа внутри или касается ли его..... если да - то делать что-то......Есть более менее хороший пример с `lineRenderer`. http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/draw-line-mouse-move-detect-line-collision-unity2d-unity3d   можете попробовать адаптировать под себя... и есть парочка моментов с `trailRenderer`

Comment: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/418759/how-might-i-go-about-making-a-trail-render-that-de.html   и http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/285040/draw-a-line-in-game.html   и...... http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/TrailRendererWith2DCollider ......... но просто чисто навесить один коллайдер вряд ли получится....

Comment: @АлексейШиманский спасибо за помощь :D

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.